# Applications of cosheaf homology?

Tags: homology, sheaf-theory

What are some applications of cosheaf homology within mathematics?
Some ones I've heard of Sheaves (not cosheaves) are computing global sections and the Picard Group with a sheaf on projective space.

Comment: I do not know anything about cosheaf *homology*.  However, cosheaves were used quite seriously by Anibal Medina in his PhD thesis.